# How to Reference the ViewModel in the View

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, mvvm, windows-phone-8

I am attempting to reference a class in my ViewModel within the xaml of my view, and I am getting an error saying `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`. THe error occurs when attemping to set the ViewModel as the Resource for a ListBox. Also, when attempting to set the ItemsSource property of my ListBox, another error results stating `The resource "effects" could not be resolved`.

MainPage.xaml

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">

        <Grid.Resources>
            //Error occurs here!
            <vm:EffectItems x:Key="effects"/>
        </Grid.Resources>

        //The ItemsSource property thus contains an error as well
        <ListBox Name="ListBoxEffects" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{StaticResource effects}" SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged"            
                 toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True"
                     ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ItemWidth="152" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="14,0,0,10" >
                        <Image Source="{Binding Thumbnail}" Width="128" Height="128" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```

I have also tried the following setup which results in the same errors on the same items

```
<ListBox Name="ListBoxEffects" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{StaticResource effects}" SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged"            
                 toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True"
                     ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ListBox.Resources>
                <vm:EffectItems x:Key="effects"/>
            </ListBox.Resources>
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" ItemWidth="152" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="14,0,0,10" >
                        <Image Source="{Binding Thumbnail}" Width="128" Height="128" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

ViewModel class

```
public class EffectItems : ObservableCollection<EffectItem>
{
    public EffectItems()
    {
        Add(new EffectItem(new BlackWhiteEffect(), "data/icons/BlackWhite.png"));
        Add(new EffectItem(new SepiaEffect(), "data/icons/Sepia.png"));
        Add(new EffectItem(new TiltShiftEffect { UpperFallOff = 0.2f, LowerFallOff = 1.0f }, "data/icons/TiltShift.png"));
        Add(new EffectItem(new PolaroidEffect { Tinting = 0.8f }, "data/icons/PolaYellow.png", "Pola"));
    }
}
```

At the top of my page I have `xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:AppName.ViewModels"` which contains no errors.

Comment: Does your viewmodel class have a parameterless constructor? Unless you're using some manner of dependency injection, if your constructor has parameters you have to instantiate it yourself somewhere.

Comment: I added my ViewModel class above, the one that is being referenced in the View. I am attempting to recreate the Codeplex sample PicFx http://picfx.codeplex.com/

Comment: can you post the complete error message including the stacktrace? Do you get the error during design time in Visual Studio or during runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You can bind your ViewModel to a View by setting the views DataContext. The straight forward way is to set it in the constructor of the code behind:

```
// Constructor
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    DataContext = new EffectItems();
}
```

Then you can set the ItemsSource of your List to the DataContext by using the default binding:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding}"
```